# Can you pass more parameters than a function expects?

Tags: php, parameter-passing

If you have two classes extending the same base class, and need to make one of them override a function to take an additional parameter. Is it okay to always pass the additional parameter when calling the function on either class?

A bit of pseudo-code to help demonstrate...

If we have the 3 classes and functions

- foo::doSomething()
- foo_subclass_one::doSomething()
- foo_subclass_two::doSomething($input)

And I have an instance of one of these three, can I call
$instance.doSomething($input)

I -think- what happens is that foo and foo_subclass_one would just ignore the additional parameter and foo_subclass_two would make use of it. Is this correct? Is there a better way I can do this if I have a lot of subclasses and really want to avoid touching 10+ files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes you can. Gather them with [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to do this:

Extend the methods to use default parameters:

```
public function doSomething($input=null) {}
```

Note that  you'll need to do this for all instances, even if it isn't used.

In this case, you may want to use the arguments array of the method:

```
public function doSomething() {
  $args = func_get_args();
  if (isset($args[0])) { $this->doSomethingElse();
}
```